# Django: Download a temporary image

Tags: python, django, dataframe, temporary-files

I am currently trying to create a function within a Django app to download a pandas dataframe as an image. I wanted to create the image as a temporary file, download it, then delete it. Does anyone know how to integrate tempfile into this code?

**Views.py**

```
def download_png(request, study):
    Names(study) #Funciton to get (name) variable
    Retrieve(study) #Function to get (data) variable
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    pngfilename = str(name) + "_" + str(current_time) + ".png"
    temp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".png")
    fig = temp.write(df2img.plot_dataframe(data))
    filepath = temp.name
    response = HttpResponse(df2img.save_dataframe(fig=fig, filename=filepath), content_type=mimetypes.guess_type(filepath))
    response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=%s" % pngfilename
    return response
```

Update 06/30/22:
I had a lot of difficulty integrating the tempfile module because it requires data to be converted to bytes-like objects. Instead I simply resolved on deleting the file after creating it.

```
def download_png(request, study):
    Names(study)
    Retrieve(study)
    pngfilename = str(name) + "_" + str(current_time) + ".png"
    mime_type, _ = mimetypes.guess_type(pngfilename)
    fig = df2img.plot_dataframe(data)
    df2img.save_dataframe(fig=fig, filename=pngfilename)
    response = FileResponse(open(pngfilename, 'rb'), content_type=mime_type)
    response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=%s" % pngfilename
    os.remove(pngfilename)
    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can use the tempfile library:

```
tempfile = tempfile.mktemp(suffix='.png')

with open(temp, 'w') as f:
    f.write(df2img.plot_dataframe(data))
    do_something_with_your_file(temp)
    os.unlink(temp)
```

Edit: was just reading the tempfile documentation and apparently `tempfile.mktemp` is prone to race conditions, so you should either use `tempfile.mkstemp` like:

```
fd, tempf = tempfile.mkstemp()
```

Or there is a context manager:

```
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as tmp:
    with open(tmp.name, 'w') as f:
        f.write('some data')
    # do something with your tempfile file
```

And then it will automatically delete the tempfile afterwards.